# Stars to appear at the end of container

Tags: flutter

I am making an app in flutter and I don't know how I can make the stars from reviews to appear at the end of that container ( and to not use a sizedBox(width:50) ) Any idea? I tried already to use the crossAligmentAxis and Main.. in the row but it didn't help.

```
  return Container(
                                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(right:12, top:8 , bottom:0),
                                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 140,
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                              boxShadow: [
                                                BoxShadow(
                                                    color: Colors.black
                                                        .withOpacity(0.1),
                                                    blurRadius: 2,
                                                    spreadRadius: 1)
                                              ],
                                              borderRadius:
                                                  BorderRadius.circular(4)),
                                          child: Column(
                                            children: [
                                              Row(
                                                children: [
                                                  CircleAvatar(
                                                    backgroundImage:
                                                        NetworkImage(snapshot
                                                            .data
                                                            .documents[index]
                                                            .data["avatarUrl"]),
                                                  ),
                                                  SizedBox(width: 8),
                                                  Text(
                                                      snapshot
                                                          .data
                                                          .documents[index]
                                                          .data["name"],
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                          fontWeight:
                                                              FontWeight.bold)),
                                                              SizedBox(width:50),
                                                                 Row(
                                                children: [
                                                  _buildRatingStars(snapshot
                                                      .data
                                                      .documents[index]
                                                      .data["rating"]),
                                                ],
                                                                 )
                                                                 ],
                                              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

there are some miss concept, here you not use children directly under row, we should try as follows:

```
Column(
          children: [
          Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage:
                NetworkImage(snapshot
                    .data
                    .documents[index]
                    .data["avatarUrl"]),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 8),
              Text(
                  snapshot
                      .data
                      .documents[index]
                      .data["name"],
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight:
                      FontWeight.bold)),
              SizedBox(width:50),
              Text(snapshot
                  .data
                  .documents[index]
                  .data["rating"])
            ],
          ),
```

Comment: This affects all orientation , I just want the stars at the end only